# Basis of Galois Field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

In our exam we were supposed to find the normal basis of $GF(3^6)$ taken as polynomial space over $GF(3^2)$. Our second task was to make the multiplication matrix for the chosen element.

Dimension of $GF(3^2)$ is 2, dimension of the extension and length of the basis is 3.

I know that $GF(3^2)$ has 9 elements, so I claim that normal basis should be in the form of $(\alpha,\alpha^9,\alpha^{81})$, $\alpha\in GF(3^6)$.

But I don't fully understand how should I make the multiplication matrix for the chosen element. Can you please show me a short example?

Comment: You need to find an irreducible polynomial of degree $3$ over $GF(3^2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over $\mathbb{F}_3$ : $x^2-2$ has no root so it is irreducible and $\mathbb{F}_{9} = \mathbb{F}_3[a]/(a^2-2)$.

Over $\mathbb{F}_{9}$ : $X^3+X+a\ $ has no root. So it is irreducible and $\mathbb{F}_{9^3} = \mathbb{F}_9[X]/(X^3+X+a)=\mathbb{F}_3[a,X]/(a^2-2,X^3+X+a)$.

In $\mathbb{F}_{9^3}$ the addition table is the same as in $\mathbb{F}_3[a,X]$, 
and the multiplication is given by $a^2 = 2$ and $X^3 = -a-X$

Comment: I used [Sage](https://cloud.sagemath.com/projects/97ce992e-ba7e-4176-8c00-4cb08a48b48f/files/GF(9%5E3).sagews) for checking $X^3+X+a$ has no root

Comment: Thank you! The very last thing, now I would like to create mult. matrix for some element $g=(a,b,c)$ in the normal basis, $a,b,c\in GF(3^2)$. $M=((g\cdot\alpha)_B, (g\cdot\alpha^{27})_B,(g\cdot\alpha^{81})_B)$. This would lead us to something like  $g\cdot\alpha=a\alpha^2+b\alpha^{10}+c\alpha^{82} \ldots$. And from the simplification we should get the matrix form. Is it correct?

Comment: @holoubekm I don't see what you mean. The elements of $\mathbb{F}_{9^3}$ are of the form $\sum_{n=0}^2 \sum_{m=0}^1 c_{n,m} X^n a^m$ where $c_{n,m} \in \mathbb{F}_ 3$. For example $aX^2$ can you multiply it with $2X+1$ ?

Comment: We were basically supposed to create the matrix for the chosen element, which applied to the other element, would have the same result as a direct multiplication. $aX^2 (2X+1) = 2aX^3+aX^2=2a(-a-X)+aX^2=aX^2-2aX-4$

Comment: @holoubekm You mean $aX^2(2X+1) = aX^2-2aX-4 = aX^2+aX-1$

Comment: @holoubekm Also finite fields multiplicative group are cyclic. $a+1$ generates $\mathbb{F}_9^\times$ so you can compute $(a+1)^k$ for $k = 0,\ldots,7$ and you'll know all the multiplication table for $\mathbb{F}_9^\times$. For $\mathbb{F}_{9^3}^\times$ you can do the same but it has $9^3-1$ elements so it will be quite long...